# Google Charts and MYSQL

Tags: php, html, mysql, google-visualization

i am new with PHP and Google charts. What i am trying to do it to make google charts with arduino data storred in a MYSL database. So far i insert data from arduino to mysql DB successfully but i face difficulties with the google charts.

**Here is my PHP code:**

```
<?php


  $mysqli =mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'Arduino');
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: ".mysqli_connect_error();
}


  $sql = mysqli_query($mysqli, 'SELECT * FROM analoog0');

  if (!$sql) {
  die("Error running $sql: " . mysql_error());
  }



  $results = array();
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql))
{
   $results[] = array(
      'Date' => $row['Date'],
      'Time' => $row['Time'],
      'Temperature' => $row['Temperature']
   );
}
$json = json_encode($results, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
echo $json;

?>
```

**Here is the JSON output:**

```
[ { "Date": "2013-10-24", "Time": "18:15:49", "Temperature": "24" }, 
{ "Date": "2013-10-24", "Time": "18:16:19", "Temperature": "24" }, 
{ "Date": "2013-10-24", "Time": "18:16:49", "Temperature": "24" }, 
{ "Date": "2013-10-24", "Time": "18:17:19", "Temperature": "23" } ]
```

**And finally the HTM code:**

```
<html>
  <head>
    <!--Load the AJAX API-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    // Load the Visualization API and the piechart package.
    google.load('visualization', '1', {'packages':['corechart']});

    // Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

    function drawChart() {
      var jsonData = $.ajax({
          url: "localhost/Charts/chart_ver2.php",
          dataType:"json",
          async: false
          }).responseText;

      // Create our data table out of JSON data loaded from server.
      var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonData);

      // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
      var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
      chart.draw(data, {width: 400, height: 240});
    }

    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="chart_div"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

When i run the HTM code nothing happens - the screen remains blank.

Any help, guidance or redirection will be highly appreciated!
Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to format the data correctly for the Visualization API.  This should put your data in the correct format:

```
$results = array(
    'cols' => array (
        array('label' => 'Date', 'type' => 'datetime'),
        array('label' => 'Temperature', 'type' => 'number')
    },
    'rows' => array()
);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql)) {
    // date assumes "yyyy-MM-dd" format
    $dateArr = explode('-', $row['Date']);
    $year = (int) $dateArr[0];
    $month = (int) $dateArr[1] - 1; // subtract 1 to make month compatible with javascript months
    $day = (int) $dateArr[2];

    // time assumes "hh:mm:ss" format
    $timeArr = explode(':', $row['Time']);
    $hour = (int) $timeArr[0];
    $minute = (int) $timeArr[1];
    $second = (int) $timeArr[2];

    $results['rows'][] = array('c' => array(
        array('v' => "Date($year, $month, $day, $hour, $minute, $second)"),
        array('v' => $row['Temperature'])
    ));
}
$json = json_encode($results, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
echo $json;
```

In your javascript, I would recommend rearranging the way you handle the AJAX query.  There's nothing wrong per say with the way you are doing it, but I think this is a more elegant solution:

```
function drawChart() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'localhost/Charts/chart_ver2.php',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (jsonData) {
            // Create our data table out of JSON data loaded from server.
            var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonData);

            // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
            var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
            chart.draw(data, {width: 400, height: 240});
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I modified my code and now i get the correct output. Can you guide me how to continue ? THanks

Comment: I still get blank screen after replacing drawChart function ;/

Comment: In a browser, go to "localhost/Charts/chart_ver2.php" and post what it outputs.

Comment: {"cols":[{"label":"Date","type":"datetime"},{"label":"Temperature","type":"number"}],"rows":[{"c":[{"v":"Date(2013, 9, 24, 18, 15, 49)"},{"v":24}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(2013, 9, 24, 18, 16, 19)"},{"v":24}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(2013, 9, 24, 18, 16, 49)"},{"v":24}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(2013, 9, 24, 18, 17, 19)"},{"v":23}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(2013, 9, 24, 18, 17, 49)"},{"v":24}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(2013, 9, 24, 18, 26, 49)"},{"v":24}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(2013, 9, 24, 18, 27, 19)"},{"v":24}]}]}

Comment: i replaced localhost/Charts/chart_ver2.php with http://localhost/Charts/chart_ver2.php and now it works ;)

Comment: I don't know if this was an artifact of the copy/paste process or not, but there is an odd character code in the "number" string in the JSON that you posted, which caused issues when I tried to test it.  I would recommend deleting and re-typing out the "number" string from the line  `array('label' => 'Temperature', 'type' => 'number')` just in case a funky character code slipped in there somehow.  If that doesn't fix the problem, open the page in Chrome, open the developer's console (ctrl+shift+j to open in Windows) and see if there are any errors reported.

Comment: Thank you, i already replaced it :) Do you know how to keep history on the chart only for the last 12 hours for example?

Comment: You will have to use a "where" clause in your SQL to restrict your data to the last 12 hours.

Comment: When i change temperature data type from integer to float, json returns value as NULL. DO you know why this happens? I tried to change the 'Temperature', 'type' => 'number'from 'number' to 'float' but it didnt work.

Comment: Don't change the type in the DataTable; "number" is the type for both ints and floats.  What did you do server-side to change the temperature to a float?

Answer (score 1):

You can't use the .responseText with a JSON response, as far as I know it only works for XML and Text.

```
$.ajax({
      url: "localhost/Charts/chart_ver2.php",
      dataType:"json",
      async: false
      }).responseText;
```

I would change it to:

```
 $.ajax({
      url: "localhost/Charts/chart_ver2.php",
      dataType:"json",
      async: false ,
      success: function(data) {
           jsonData = data;
       }
      });
```